# Encryption certificates must contain Data Encipherment or Key Encipherment

Tags: powershell, certificate, x509certificate, dsc

After upgrading to Windows Management Framework 5.0, I have started to receive the following exception when sourcing a DSC configuration.

```
ConvertTo-MOFInstance : System.ArgumentException error processing property 'Password' OF TYPE 'MSFT_Credential': Certificate
'---HIDDEN-CERTIFICATE-THUMPRINT-VALUE---' cannot be used for encryption. Encryption certificates must contain the Data Encipherment or Key
Encipherment key usage, and include the Document Encryption Enhanced Key Usage (1.3.6.1.4.1.311.80.1).
At C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSDesiredStateConfiguration\PSDesiredStateConfiguration.psm1:303 char:13
+             ConvertTo-MOFInstance MSFT_Credential $newValue
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Write-Error], InvalidOperationException
```

The certificate being is used on each node is a self-signed certificate that is generated using the following certificate request.

```
[NewRequest]
Subject = CN=[computer-name-here].dsc
KeyLength = 2048
MachineKeySet = true
RequestType = Cert
KeySpec = AT_KEYEXCHANGE
```

This request file is then fed to the `certreq` command line utility to generate the cert and load it into `cert:\LocalMachine\My` certificate store.

I have tried adding the following to my certificate request file, based on the [documentation for the certreq tool](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn296456.aspx), but I still am getting the same failure.

```
KeyUsage = 0x30
[Strings]
szOID_ENHANCED_KEY_USAGE = "1.3.6.1.4.1.311.80.1"
```

Setting `KeyUsage` to `0x30` enables both key encipherment and data encipherment.  However I am cannot seem to find details about the enhanced key usage in the generated certificate. Perhaps I'm setting this value incorrectly in the request.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the blog post [PowerShell V5 New Feature: Protect/Unprotect-CmsMessage](https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2015/01/08/powershell-v5-new-feature-protectunprotect-cmsmessage/) by Keith Hill, which doesn't directly relate to this issue but it does show how to define a certificate request file that contains the Document Encryption key usage.

I now generate a self signed certificate using the following request inf:

```
[Version]
Signature = "$Windows NT$"

[Strings]
szOID_ENHANCED_KEY_USAGE = "2.5.29.37"
szOID_DOCUMENT_ENCRYPTION = "1.3.6.1.4.1.311.80.1"

[NewRequest]
Subject = "CN=test.dsc"
KeyLength = 2048
MachineKeySet = true
RequestType = Cert
KeySpec = AT_KEYEXCHANGE
KeyUsage = CERT_KEY_ENCIPHERMENT_KEY_USAGE

[Extensions]
%szOID_ENHANCED_KEY_USAGE% = "{text}%szOID_DOCUMENT_ENCRYPTION%"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the New-SelfSignedCertificate cmdlet to generate the self signed certificate as well. I wrote this module which will help generate a certificate as required by DSC https://github.com/nanalakshmanan/xDSCUtils

Comment: I do like the pure powershell version you put together, rather than relying on `certreq`.